# Select also zero-values while performing SELECT COUNT with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I'm in the middle of creating stats module. One of my jobs is to create plot with sums of registered users for past week.
The problem is that I work on a service that is being used by only few of our customers, so days when noone registers happen quite often.

Table description (simplified) is:

```
TABLE users:
============
id serial NOT NULL,
date_created timestamp with timezone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
```

to get sums for last 7 days, I use

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as ile,
    DATE_TRUNC('day', date_created) as day
FROM
    users
WHERE
    date_created >= now() - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2
```

Everything works fine, Postgres returns for example:

```
ile | day
===========================
2   | "2013-09-23 00:00:00"
1   | "2013-09-25 00:00:00"
```

EXCEPT it ommits days with 0 count. 
Of course I have to parse results of this query (in this case: PHP + Symfony) so I could just iterate through desired date range and fill the blanks, but I wonder if there's **simple** way to ask PostgreSQL to do it for me, so it returns something like this:

```
ile | day
===========================
2   | "2013-09-23 00:00:00"
0   | "2013-09-24 00:00:00"
1   | "2013-09-25 00:00:00"
0   | "2013-09-26 00:00:00"
0   | "2013-09-27 00:00:00"
0   | "2013-09-28 00:00:00"
0   | "2013-09-29 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test at the moment, but you can use [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function:

```
select
    count(u.id) as ile,
    d.day
from generate_series('2013-09-23'::date, '2013-09-29'::date, '1d') as d(day)
    left outer join users as u on u.date_created >= d.day and u.date_created < d.day + '1d'::interval
    -- or left outer join users as u on date_trunc('day', u.date_created) = d.day
    -- but I think that >= and < will be faster if you have index on `date_created`
group by d.day
```

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't aware that I can perform join with >= or <.  It's monday and I've learned something new today. Thanks! :) Query works but not perfectly - it gives wrong results, I guess that's becouse generate_series returns timestamps with timezones, and there's timestamp **without** timezone in `users` relation... but I guess that's something that I'll dig myself. Big thanks!